# Is it possible to change the default play icon for video tags on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, video, ipod-touch

I'm working on a mobile-optimized version of a client site that contains many HTML5 video tags. When viewing on the iPhone it's displaying the default play button watermark. Is it possible to customize this icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in the HTML, because the play icon you're seeing is in fact an (undocumented) UIButton subclass that's laid on-top of the webpage. It's not an HTML element, it's a UIKit one.

I have messed around in the past with modifying this button, but you need to perform various dodgy operations on a UIWebView from Objective-C, not HTML, so it's probably not much help to you (even if it was, it's all undocumented so not suitable for production use anyway).